# Android: How to print running text to the screen

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask

I have a back-end process running (AsyncTask). I am interested in printing out System.out.println(); to the screen (something like the console in Eclipse) with information so the user is informed which calculations are running in the back.

What I wish to accomplish is seeing the text running on the screen - something like a dialog on top of the currenly-in-focus activity.

Does anyone got experience with this?

Thanks, D.

Comment: You have to pass in a context into the AsyncTask's constructor that way you will be able to display a dialog. On an other note you might want to mark some of your prior answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can hijack System.out.print() and send it to the screen. But you can make a TextView and send the new lines of text to it as they are ready. Something like this should work.

```
String outputStr = "";

//Whenever you want to add a line to the TextView do it like this:
outputStr += "\n" + [yourNewText];
mTxt.setText(outputStr);
```

If you were to add lots of lines in this manner would appear to the user as the same sort of situation as the eclipse console.

Since you can do this with a TextView you could then add that TextView to a custom dialog and show it to the user.

Comment: Thanks! this works great. I have the `outputStr += "\n" + [yourNewText];` part inside the `doInBackground()` and the `mTxt.setText(outputStr);` inside `onProgressUpdate()` so it writes the actual line. I set `outputStr` as a member variable of `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need to be in the UI thread to update a textview. In an asynctask, you call [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29), which is then executed in the UI thread. Otherwise, you can use [view.post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or you can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Hi @James Coote - do you believe I could use `publishProgress()`->`onProgressUpdate()` in the way @Tim mentioned? Meaning I can send My strings with notifications of progress to a custom dialog showing over the Activity running in the main thread?

Comment: Sure, that was what I was suggesting :) Also, as @Sbossb suggests, you can do this by passing the `context` into the constructor of the `AsyncTask`. You need to be a bit careful though as holding onto the `context` can cause memory leaks when the activity is restarted/recreated (such as when the user hits home button, then comes back to the app later). I usually have my `AsyncTasks` as inner classes of my `Activity`, so I can access the `context` using `MyActivity.this`

Comment: Thanks James - this is very informative. I wrote a remark below Tim's answer. I managed to implement this without the use of passing the context. Thanks about the information about a memLeak - it is always good to know!  :)